# C# WPF How to create TextBlock programmatically with parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying create GanttChart using Class GantRowPanel from this article:
[GanttChart](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/how-to-create-gantt-control-in-wpf.html)

In my MainWindow.xaml I have:

```
<UI:GanttRowPanel x:Name="Gantt" MinDate="09:00" MaxDate="17:00">
        <TextBlock Text="Work" UI:GanttRowPanel.StartDate="09:00" UI:GanttRowPanel.EndDate="12:00"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Lunch" UI:GanttRowPanel.StartDate="12:00" UI:GanttRowPanel.EndDate="13:00"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Work" UI:GanttRowPanel.StartDate="13:00" UI:GanttRowPanel.EndDate="17:00"/>
    </UI:GanttRowPanel>
```

How to add TextBlock programmatically, from CodeBehind to Gantt ?

I was trying this:

[image]

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It seems that you did the right job. `Not work` means what?, can't see anything or any exception?

Comment: Where is the definition of GanttRowPanel?

Comment: Please answer @Iron 's question. What does "But it doesn't work." mean?

Comment: can't see anything, I even add background color to be sure. If I declare Textblock in mainwindow.xaml, everything works fine, but I need to add TextBlock programmatically.

Comment: The `DateTime ` range in the XAML is not right, just try the solution my answer.

Comment: XAML sample works fine, the date is correct. I have problem with do the same thing frome code behind, the goal is to generate TextBlock from SQL result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, the `DateTime` range is not right. Without setting the date, the default date will be `0001-1-1`, which not contains the date range in the code-behind. So you should keep the same `DateTime` style in the XAML and code-behind.

You should add `date` to the `MinDate` and the `MaxDate` in the XAML:

```
<UI:GanttRowPanel x:Name="Gantt" MinDate="2017-10-15 09:00" MaxDate="2017-10-15 17:00">
</UI:GanttRowPanel>
```

Alternatively, remove the `date` in the code-behind:

```
ui.GanttRowPanel.SetStartDate(txBlock, DateTime.Parse("09:00"));
ui.GanttRowPanel.SetEndDate(txBlock, DateTime.Parse("15:00"));
```

Comment: XAML sample works fine, the date is correct. I have problem with do the same thing frome code behind.

Comment: In the XAML, all items keep the same: only have `time` without setting `date`. So they have the same `date`, it works well. In the XAML, all items keep the same: only have `time` without setting `date`. So the have the same `date`, it works well. You can also achieve in code-behind without setting date: `DateTime.Parse("09:00")` and ``DateTime.Parse("15:00")``.

Comment: Not working, maybe something is missing... maybe there is no connection with txBlock and ui.GanttRowPanel.SetStartDate(txBlock,DateTime.Parse("09:00")); and class simply cant see it ? Like I said I am new and without experienced ind WPF C#

Comment: Just keep the same `DateTime` style in the `XAML` and `code-behind`, and make sure the `TextBlock`'s `StartDate` and `EndDate` is between the `MinDate` and `MaxDate` of the `GanttRowPanel`. I have achieve it in my demo.

Comment: Could you please give me your Email?

Comment: I have debugged the source code of the `GanttRowPanel`, it was indeed cased by the `DateTime` style, causing the `TextBlock` was put `outside` of the `GanttRowPanel`.

Comment: halilidi@ether123.net  it is temporary mail, thank you for help :)

Comment: Check your email please.